# What are the non-obvious implications of using OpenId in a website?

Tags: openid

For example, I use my gmail ID to log into SO. What happens if I delete my gmail account?

a. Will I be notified that I am using it to log into SO as well? 
b. What if I want to delete my gmail account but still want to use my SO account? From a 'dumb' users perspective will I have to jump through hoops to be able to do this?
c. etc?

EDIT: Why would someone want to close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read Rob Conery's [experience](http://blog.wekeroad.com/thoughts/open-id-is-a-party-that-happened) using OpenID.  You may not agree with it, but it does provide food for thought.

Comment: Many many thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. And infact I completely agree with Rob Conery. I am also both a developer and a business owner and I worry about end users. This question was kicked from Programmers to here and then someone voted for it to be closed. Not to offend anyone but you'd have to be an absolute idiot at business if you jumped to using openID without answering the question I asked.